# showing 3 Images in a table row from a list of 10 images or more - PHP

Tags: php

in a database there are some images [of unknown number], i need to show them 3 in a row
here is my code, but it does not work [in some row it shows 2 or 4 photos] :(

```
<?php
$temp=0;
$stmt = mysqli_prepare($con,"select PicName from Pic_Details");
mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
mysqli_stmt_bind_result($stmt,$picName);
while(mysqli_stmt_fetch($stmt))
{
 if ($temp % 3==0)
   echo '<tr>';

 echo '<td valign="top" width="150px"><img src="'.$picName.'"/></td>';

if ($temp % 3==0)
   echo '</tr>';
++$temp;
}

?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following... ofcourse if you have a total number of pics that isnt divisble by three you need to work in some logic to detect that and add pad to 3 cells on the last row.

```
<?php
$temp=0;
$stmt = mysqli_prepare($con,"select PicName from Pic_Details");
mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
mysqli_stmt_bind_result($stmt,$picName);
while(mysqli_stmt_fetch($stmt))
{
 if ($temp % 3==0 )
   echo '<tr>';

 echo '<td valign="top" width="150px"><img src="'.$picName.'"/></td>';

if ($temp % 3==2) // remainder should be 2 on the last cell
   echo '</tr>';
++$temp;
}

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I just think you have a problem with your conditionals.

I would test this here and clean up the code a bit:

```
if ($stmt = mysqli_prepare($con,"select PicName from Pic_Details")) {

    echo "<table>";
    while(mysqli_stmt_fetch($stmt)) {
        echo ($temp % 3 != 0) ? '' : '<tr>';
        echo '<td valign="top" width="150px"><img src="{$picName}"/></td>';
        echo ($temp % 3 != 0) ? '' : '</tr>';
    ++$temp;
    }
    echo "</table>";

} else {
  echo "failed at: mysqli_prepare";
}
```